# Magento 2: How to programatically mark product image as hidden from product page?

Tags: product, product-images, image, magento-2.1.3

I'm trying to programatically set the "Hide from Product Page" setting on an image.

The setting can be found here: Products > Catalog > (select a product) > Images And Videos > (click on an image).

[image: Image showing the setting.]

So far, the only way I've been able to change that setting, is by doing it manually.

Here's how I currently add images to my products:

```
$product->addImageToMediaGallery($imagePath, ['thumbnail'], false, true);
$product->save();
```

I thought that the last parameter which is called `exclude` and described as `mark image as excluded from product page view` would do the trick, but it doesn't. Regardless of if I set the value to `true`or `false`, the image remains visible on the product page and the checkbox is unchecked.

I've been banging my head against a wall for the better part of a day now, so any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, after introducing multiple store views, the code above hides the images in some store views, rather than all of them.

To fix this, I changed the code to

```
$product->setStoreId(0)->addImageToMediaGallery($imagePath, ['thumbnail'], false, true);
$product->save();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simply change product image visibility using a database.

If you want disabled all product images so run the below query in the database.

```
UPDATE `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value` SET `disabled` = '1' WHERE `disabled` = '0';
```

If you want to enable all product images so run the below query in the database.

```
UPDATE `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value` SET `disabled` = '0' WHERE `disabled` = '1';
```

Thanks

Comment: It works, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I had a same situation.

I imported products with images, but **I wanted to hide the first image of all products on the detail pages**.

(This first image is set as *small_image*, *thumbnail_image*, and *swatch_image* in the product import CSV. I want them to show up on the product list pages, but I do NOT want them to show up on the galley section of the product detail pages.)

I searched online, but there seem to be no easy solution to achieve this.

So, I decided to create a comnand line custom PHP script to change DB values without using Magento2 PHP classes.

***(It is NOT advised to directly change DB values. Please use this solution with your own discretion. Always take DB backups before trying this solution.)***

As a preparation, I checked how the DB data is changed by setting "Hide from Product Page". I changed it for one product, then compared DB dumps of BEFORE and AFTER states.

It turned out **catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value** is the only table affected by this setting change.

This is the BEFORE state for product entity_id=42
[image]

This is the AFTER state of product entity_id=42
[image]

As you can see, "value_id", "stor_id", "entity_id", "position", and "disabled" are unchanged. However, the last field "**record_id**" is updated.

Also, the "**disabled**" value is changed from **0** to **1** for the 2nd entry with "position value == 1".

It turned out, every time I updated the image settings on a product, the entries on this table are re-created with new "**record_id**" field values.

With this knowledge, I created this command line PHP script (file name: **img-update.php**).

```
<?php

// create ID list for products

$idList = array();
$handle = fopen("img-update-product-id-list.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($id = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        $idList[] = rtrim($id);
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
$idListStr = join(",", $idList);

// create PHP array representing catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value data

$productList = array();

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$dbname = "";
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: ". $conn->connect_error);
}
echo  "Connection success\n";

$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value` WHERE `entity_id` IN (" . $idListStr . ")";
$result = $conn->query($sql1);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $productList[] = array(
            "value_id" => $row["value_id"],
            "store_id" => $row["store_id"],
            "entity_id" => $row["entity_id"],
            "position" => $row["position"],
            "disabled" => $row["disabled"],
            "record_id" => $row["record_id"],
            "is2nd" => false,
        );
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results.\n";
}

// determine the 2nd entry for position 1 image which activates "Hide from Product Page" setting

$entityIdList = array();

foreach($productList as $key => $p) {
    if ($p['position'] == 1) {
        if (in_array($p['entity_id'], $entityIdList)) {
            $productList[$key]['is2nd'] = true;
        } else {
            $entityIdList[] = $p['entity_id'];
        }
    }
}

// update entries

$value_id = $store_id = $entity_id = $position = $disabled = "";

$sql2 = "ALTER TABLE `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value` DISABLE KEYS";
$conn->query($sql2);
foreach($productList as $index => $p) {

    $value_id = $p["value_id"];
    $store_id = $p["store_id"];
    $entity_id = $p["entity_id"];
    $position = $p["position"];
    $disabled = $p["disabled"];

    $is2nd = $p["is2nd"];

    if ($is2nd) {
        $sql2 = "INSERT INTO `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value` (`value_id`, `store_id`, `entity_id`, `label`, `position`, `disabled`) VALUES (" . $value_id . "," . $store_id . "," . $entity_id . ",''," . $position . ",1)";
    } else {
        $sql2 = "INSERT INTO `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value` (`value_id`, `store_id`, `entity_id`, `label`, `position`, `disabled`) VALUES (" . $value_id . "," . $store_id . "," . $entity_id . ",''," . $position . ",0)";
    }

    $conn->query($sql2);
    echo '+';  // progress indicator
}
$sql2 = "ALTER TABLE `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value` ENABLE KEYS";
$conn->query($sql2);

echo "\n";

// remove old entries

$sql3 = "ALTER TABLE `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value` DISABLE KEYS";
$conn->query($sql3);
foreach($productList as $index => $p) {

    $value_id = $p["value_id"];
    $store_id = $p["store_id"];
    $entity_id = $p["entity_id"];
    $position = $p["position"];
    $disabled = $p["disabled"];

    $record_id = $p["record_id"];

    $sql3 = "DELETE FROM `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value` WHERE `value_id` = " . $value_id . " AND `store_id` = " . $store_id  . " AND `entity_id` = " . $entity_id . " AND `position` = " . $position . " AND `record_id` = " . $record_id;
    $conn->query($sql3);
    echo '-';  // progress indicator
}
$sql3 = "ALTER TABLE `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value` ENABLE KEYS";
$conn->query($sql3);

echo "\n";

$conn->close();
```

There is a companion text file used with this PHP script. The file name is **img-update-product-id-list.txt**.

```
41
42
43
....
....
....
860
861
862
863
864
865
```

Place both **img-update.php** and **img-update-product-id-list.txt** file to the root directory of Magento 2 installation, and run the script as **php img-update.php** from your terminal.

Modify the .txt and .php files to suite your setup.